# How do i get a column not to show if there are no results in that particular columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am reviewing companies total capacity for 4 seperate risks, columns B-E, with cells A14-A46 being the list of companies being reviewed. If a company has a - in the cell for capacity for a risk, how do i get that column (e.g. A15) not to show in my data but still exist?

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Hi catling94, welcome to Super User. Perhaps it is clear to others but what is confusing me is that `A15` in your example is a cell, not a column- perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: If you can add an image it is probably easy to understand it

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without the formula or data in A15, but you could add an `IF Statement` to your cell(s). For example,

```
=IF(A15="-","",whatever A15 should equal)
```

Basically, you are saying if A15 equals "-" then leave it blank otherwise let A15 be A15.